# Choose a model when the Hosmer and Lemeshow test is significant

Tags: regression, logistic

I am using logistic regression (PROC LOGISTIC) and for both of my two models, the Hosmer and Lemeshow Test is significant. I also computed AUC :

AUC(model 1) = 0.583 and AUC(model 2) = 0.604.

How can I choose one of them ?

Comment: You reject the model if the goodness of fit is not good enough. That means your models are not good fit.

Comment: Hosmer Lemeshow goodness of fit test has a glitch in it, for larger set of data >1000 observations ? (I have 1650000 observations)

Comment: in this case don't worry the test just look at AUC.

Comment: The Hosmer-Lemeshow test is notoriously underpowered. Therefore, if you reject the null, that often indicates gross lack-of-fit. I wouldn't use the model. This is consistent with the very bad AUC values (even for the "better" model). As a sidebar: always be cautious with this test, because it can depend heavily on the arbitrary choice of the number of groups chosen.

Comment: So what should I do ? is there another test or method ? I am using SAS

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe look to see whether there are non-linear effects (polynomial terms or interactions perhaps) and see whether that improves the fit, because a failed Hosmer-Lemeshow test often relates to a misspecified model. The low AUC could mean model misspecification or just predictors that are not very strongly associated with the outcome. Do you have other data you can bring in?

Comment: Ok. No, I dont have other data. I use "The Select SAS macro" to do variable selection. Now i get a model like this : Y = X1 X2 X1*X2. and this model's AUC equals 0.6204 and The Hosmer-Lemeshow test gave me 1 as p-value and 0.000 as Khi-2. It's good or bad ?

Comment: $\chi^2 = 0$ means the observed exactly matches the expected, which sounds like you might have saturated the model. I don't understand how the AUC could be 0.62 under those circumstances, unless you have very large and heterogeneous groups in the calculation of the HL test statistic, in which case you might want to increase the number of groups.

Comment: I have more than 100 000 observations in my data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model 2 has the higher area under the response curve. So it therefore appears to be slightly better.

Comment: A significant Hosmer-Lemeshow test does not necessarily mean that a predictive model is not useful or suspect ?

Comment: This is consistent with the response I gave in my answer.